# ElasticSearch + Rails multiple `must` not working correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-model

As per docs I am using this syntax:

```
self.search(
  query: {
    bool: {
      must: { match: { type: 'user' } },
      must: { match: { status: status } },
      must: { range: { created_at: { from: date_from, to: date_to } } }
    }
  },
  size: 1000
)
```

I believe it should be looking for all 3 conditions, but query is ignoring all `must` but last:

`<Elasticsearch::Model::Searching::SearchRequest:0x000000039b2c08
     @definition=
      {:index=>"uusers",
       :type=>"user",
       :body=>{:query=>{:bool=>{:must=>{:range=>{:created_at=>{:from=>Mon, 25 Aug 2014, :to=>Thu, 18 May 2017}}}}}, :size=>1000}}`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have multiple statements, you must add it inside an array, like below:

```
self.search(
  query: {
    bool: {
      must: [
        { match: { type: 'user' } },
        { match: { status: status } },
        { range: { created_at: { from: date_from, to: date_to } } }
      ]
    }
  },
  size: 1000
)
```

Comment: I was sure I tried it already, but I didn't. Thanks, this worked well